# SNORT sfportscan alert format

Tags: ids, snort

How  can I modify the output alert from sfportscan ?

Ex : `output alert_csv: /var/log/snort/portscan.log timestamp,src,dst,dstport,msg`

OBS: I can set output for default alert file with this method ?

Comment: All what I know is that you can. You will need to modify `snort.conf`. How ? I never did it.

Comment: I need it for integrate with OSSEC ,if nobody show me a good answer i will developer a script :(

Answer (score 0):

I Developer a script for filter the sfportscan log and integrate it with OSSEC

SNORT(sfportscan) -> portscan.log < filter.py > portscan-filter.log < OSSEC Regex >

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a = ""
f = open("/var/log/snort/portscan.log","r")
s = open("/var/log/snort/portscan-filter.log","w")
while 1:
    where = f.tell()
    line = f.readline()
    s.seek(where)
    if line[:4] == "Time": a = line 
    elif "(portscan)" in line:
         a = a.replace("\n","")
         line = line.replace("\n","")
         ray = ','.join([a,line])
         print (ray) 
         s.write(ray+"\n")
         a = ""
    else:
        pass
f.close()
```

**Output:** `Time: 01/02-12:34:56.006648 ,10.147.160.122 -> 177.124.192.123 (portscan) TCP Filtered Portscan`


And i made this **Regex** for integrate with **decode** OSSEC rule: `(\S+) ,(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) -> (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) (\(\w+\) .+)`